# GAE PHP - URL Fetch

Tags: google-app-engine

According to the documents when making a call to another App Engine app:

```
If you are making requests to another App Engine app, you should consider telling the UrlFetch service to not follow redirects when invoking it.
```

Up until now, there is no documentation on how to edit the function and tell the service not to follow redirects, so does anyone know the trick ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set the

```
follow_redirects = false
```

When invoking fetch.

**Standard call with fetch**

```
fetch(url, payload=None, method=GET, headers={}, 
allow_truncated=False, follow_redirects=True, deadline=5,
validate_certificate=False)
```

Change the **follow_redirects to false** like this

```
 fetch(url, payload=None, method=GET, headers={}, 
 allow_truncated=False, follow_redirects=False, deadline=5,
 validate_certificate=False)
```

**PHP**

```
$context = [
    'http' => [
    'method' => 'get',
    'header' => "custom-header: custom-value\r\n" . "custom-header-two: custome-value-2\r\n",
    'content' => $data,
    'follow_location' => false,
    ]
];
```

Comment: I guess this is for Python, is it the same for PHP ?

Comment: Should be if I'm not wrong try it.